# RegEx Delphi \ Поиск значений

Tags: регулярные-выражения, delphi

В текстовом файле, все строки, **разной длины**. В строках имеются - **спец-символы, буквы, цифры и пробелы...**

**Пример строк:**

```
'a1~a1.aa' тут текст 'a1~a1.aa' тут текст 'a1~a1.aa' тут текст 'a1~a1.aa'
"b2~b2.bb) тут текст  "b2~b2.bb) тут текст  "b2~b2.bb) 
c1~c3.cc тут текст c1~c3.cc тут текст
```

**Вопрос:** Как вытащить, все значения, с текстового файла - что находяться между - любыми **спец-символами** и в которых имеются **(обязательно)** символы плюс (**~** и **.**). То есть текст может находится между **любыми** спец-символами и длина текста, между спец-символами **может быть разной**....

**В итоге, должен получится результат:**

```
a1~a1.aa
a1~a1.aa
a1~a1.aa
a1~aa.aa
b2~b2.bb
b2~b2.bb
b2~b2.bb
c1~c3.cc
c1~c3.cc
```

**Пробовала составить регулярное выражение вот так (не корректно работает):**

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+~[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b
```

Какое, правильное, регулярное выражение - для этой задачи или, в данном случае, можно обойтись без регулярных выражений ?... Знаю что задача не простая... поэтому и прошу помощи.

**Дополнение (делаю так) к ответу пользователя - Uladzimir Palekh:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fall, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
  i: integer;
  RegExp: TRegExpr;
begin
  RegExp := TRegExpr.Create;

  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    reset(fall);

    AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\Save_Rez.txt');
    rewrite(f1);

    RegExp.Expression := '["':;
    ^! + \ - ()\[\]\ \ { } \ / <> ,.# & $]([0 - 9 a - zA - Z] +
      ~[0 - 9 a - zA - Z] + \.[0 - 9 a - zA - Z] + )
      ['":;^!+\-()\[\]\\{}\/<>,.#&$]';

    while not Eof(fall) do
    begin

      ReadLn(fall, S);

      if (RegExp.Exec(S)) then
        writeln(f1, S);
    end;

    CloseFile(fall);
    CloseFile(f1);

  end;
end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: уточните. что вы включаете в понятие спец.символа?

Comment: @teran, Ну спецсимволы это вот такого плана знаки :;^!+-()[]\{}/<>,.#"&$

Comment: Спецсимволы парные или же текст между двумя любыми спецсимволами?

Comment: @Uladzimir Palekh, Просто текст - между двумя любыми спецсимволами ( Одинаковыми или разными).

Comment: Ваш пример кода вообще не должен компилироваться, так как и одинарная кавычка не экранирована, и само регулярное выражение на несколько строк разбито. Кстати, с самим регулярным выражением вы тоже работаете неправильно.

Comment: @Uladzimir Palekh, Можете привести код - как правильно все должно быть ?... А то я уже запуталась....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я исключил из спецсимволов точку, поскольку не объяснено, как обрабатывать в том случае, если она является и ограничителем, и должна находиться внутри.

```
procedure ExtractSMTH(const s: string; reslt: TStrings);
var
  state, i, start: integer;
begin
  state := 0;
  start := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(s) do
    case s[i] of
      ':', ';', '^', '!', '+', '-', '(', ')', '[', ']',
      '\', '{', '}', '/', '<',
      '>', ',', '#', '"', '''', '&', '$':  begin
          if state = 7 then
            reslt.add(Copy(s, start + 1, i - start - 1));
          state := 1;
          start := i;
        end;
      '~': if state > 0 then
         state := state or 2;
       '.': if state > 0 then
         state := state or 4;
    end;
end;

begin
   ExtractSMTH('''a1~a1.aa'' тут текст ''a1~a1.aa'' тут текст ''a1~a1.aa'' тут текст ''a1~a1.aa''', Memo1.Lines);
   ExtractSMTH('"b2~b2.bb) тут текст  "b2~b2.bb) тут текст  "b2~b2.bb)', Memo1.Lines);
end;

a1~a1.aa
a1~a1.aa
a1~a1.aa
a1~a1.aa
b2~b2.bb
b2~b2.bb
b2~b2.bb
```

Comment: И последний вопрос, у вас вывод результатов идет в memo1. А по сути дела нужно что бы в файл. То есть открыли входной файл обработали и результат записали в - выходной файл. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: tstringlist передавайте процедуре, потом его сохранить

Comment: Это как ? ну в смысле... То есть не могу понять принцип... Заранее извините за такие вопросы..

Comment: Ну ничего себе.... Создайте экземпляр TStringList. Используйте его как параметр  вместо Memo.Lines. После обработки всех строк сделайте SaveToFile

Comment: Ой...ой... я поняла... А то голова забита сегодня целый день... Извините за вопрос... Делаю..

Comment: Ответила на свой вопрос... Сделала как Вы сказали... Посмотрите ответ...

Answer (score 1):

С учётом информации из комментариев, у меня получилось [вот такое выражение](https://regex101.com/r/3YosTA/1):

```
["':;^!+\-()\[\]\\{}\/<>,.#&$]([0-9a-zA-Z]+~[0-9a-zA-Z]+\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)['":;^!+\-()\[\]\\{}\/<>,.#&$]
```

Однако в нём используются следующие допущения:

1. Текст для поиска имеет формат `x~x.x`, где `x` это одна или более цифра или буква латинского алфавита.
2. Пробел и перевод строки не является спецсимволом.

С учётом допущения 2, это регулярное выражение не может найти обе строки `c1~c3.cc` из примера исходных данных.

Comment: У меня почему то просто строки копирует и все, то есть данные по заданным параметрам не вытягивает.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример вашего кода, так как само регулярное выражение тривиально.

Comment: Добавила, посмотрите пожалуйста...